# Angular 2 Conditional Required Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I've created a Conditional Required Directive for Angular 2 from Thierry Templier's post [Angular 2 conditional Validators.required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118721/angular-2-conditional-validators-required).

It works fine but I would like to change the styles on the control whose value is being evaluated (one for valid, one for invalid), but only if it's value is required.  I've been trying to do this by either dynamically adding the "required" attribute to the control or by changing the class in the directive.  Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful with either method.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: I had similar issue and solved it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40093790/1876949. Might be useful to you as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer Sasxa.  It was very useful and helped me solve this issue by using this.renderer.setElementClass(this.control, 'has-value', this.control.value !== '').